# undefined message when trying to get attr id value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

All,

This is simple but can't seem to figure this out.  I have a close function that should display out the value of the attribute id.  But I get a message of undefined in my alert message.  Thanks for any help.

href code:

```
     <a href="javascript:close()">
       <img class="close-icon" alt="" />
     </a>
```

function:

```
    function close() {
        var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('ID clicked on: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
     }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I have a div around the href.  and that my div does have a value for id.

Comment: also my page is a content page.

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` nor `<img>` has an attribute id. Add one into `<a>` tag and it'll work fine. Also, don't use `javascript:` in `href`, do `onclick` event

Comment: thanks for the reponse!  I forgot to mention that I have a div around my href and that my div has a value for id.  I also have this page as a content page in asp.net.

Comment: @Mde so you need to use $(this).parent().attr('id');

Comment: var currentID = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');

Comment: Thanks guys ....I have tried both solutions but still get undefined as the output message in my alert.  I'm using a content page in asp.net .....does this make a difference?